# Why new order is created after 'edit' action in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, orders

I wonder why new order is created after editing old one? I think this is pretty hard to be implemented but I believe there are another reasons for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an order should not be changed once is created (except for the status).
When changing an order, the price can change, some shipping charges can change or a certain shipping method may not be available. Also, the payment method for the old order may not be available to the new order.

Creating a new order solves these problems.